# How to detect bad sectors in low use drives?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have many Linux machines. Those are dedicated servers in data centers (Hetzner for example). There are some very old files that are never accessed by any process in the system.

I periodically test the S.M.A.R.T. status of the hard disks. Is this enough to make sure I don't have data loss?

Taking the system offline and running disk checking utilities is usually difficult since the servers are production servers.

How do I reliably view the complete health of these drives?

Comment: SMART tests won’t really help much in this scenario, you might want to look into something like ZFS which can do scheduled online checks/repairs for data corruption

Comment: If you simply want to make sure all sectors on HDD are read use `dd` on the whole disk/partition and write the read data to `/dev/null`. You can do that while the system is running as you don't care what is being read.

Comment: I think HDDs have no means to detect bad sectors, except when trying to read sectors. In theory the drive may read all data over and over again by itself, but this would unnecessarily strain the mechanics of the drive. Such test can be performed on demand though: internally (`smartctl -t long`) or by just reading the whole HDD. The latter method is what @Robert is talking about. We need no features specific to `dd` here, so `cat /dev/sdx >/dev/null` or `pv /dev/sdx >/dev/null` (if we want to see the progress) will do. Some controllers or filesystems may have their own ways.

Comment: Vote to reopen: this question has a fact-based answer.  A "bad sector" means that a write will not retain the data, and/or the read has numerous bit errors that are uncorrectable.  Either of these conditions can only be detected by reading the sector/LBA.  The extended or long test in SMART can efficiently read every sector/LBA of the drive with minimal impact to the host computer.  Whereas a **dd** command can also read but also consume I/O resources of the host computer (e.g. meaningless SATA transfers).

Comment: I have had numerous drives fail over the years, not a single one would have been saved, by tracking the current status of the S.M.A.R.T data.  While there might have been signs, in most cases of fail sectors, the end result was the Windows couldn't boot suddenly.  I can only think of a single instance, which I ignored other signs, and could have been prevented before the drive suddenly failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux we have

```
 badblocks -s -v /dev/sda
```

This command is nice because it doesn't cause any downtime. Just slows down the drive with the extra workload.

The only bad news is you have to examine the results manually yourself.

For some file system types you can manually feed in the resulting bad sector list.  However, I don't have that information handy.

Aside from this you would have to use SHA2 hashes on ALL the files.  There is a parity program called QuickPar which you could generate recovery data.  However, I am not sure if this is available for linux.

I believe BTRFS has something built-in where you can do a chksum scan, but I am not sure on what kind of errors it can recover.

The best bet is hardware as in a RAID6 solution.  Get bad sectors, replace the drive, and the other drives will rebuild the missing data.

I believe ZFS has a software RAID mode, but as with RAID 6 you would have to move ALL the data off, reformat, create the new ZFS raid setup, and restore your data.